# Flutter trying to compile my deleted Project

Tags: flutter

I'm currently working on  a Flutter project named 'health_service' but Flutter is trying to compile other project named 'flare_test1' which was deleted and is in Trash.

I thought there might be a problen in cache.
So I did `flutter clean` but the result is same.

Here's output of `flutter doctor`

> [✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.6
>   18G95, locale ja-JP) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android
>   devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and
>   macOS (Xcode 10.3) [✓] Android Studio (version 3.4) [✓] VS Code
>   (version 1.37.1) [✓] Connected device (1 available)

`flutter --version`

> Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.2 • channel unknown • unknown source Framework •
>   revision 2d2a1ffec9 (9일 전) • 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700 Engine •
>   revision b863200c37 Tools • Dart 2.5.0

Here's the log when I `flutter run`.

`Xcode's output:
↳

> Unhandled exception:
>       Crash when compiling package:flare_test1/main.dart,
>       at character offset null:
>       Unexpected Kernel version 30 (expected 29).
>       #0      BinaryBuilder.readComponent (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:450:7)
>       #1      ProcessedOptions.loadComponent (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:393:10)
>       #2      ProcessedOptions.loadSdkSummary (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:331:32)
>       
>       #3      generateKernelInternal. (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:82:42)
>       
>       #4      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:24)
>       
>       #5      generateKernelInternal (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:69:10)
>       
>       #6      kernelForProgramInternal. (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:60:35)
>       
>       #7      CompilerContext.runWithOptions. (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:134:20)
>       
>       #8      CompilerContext.runInContext..
>   (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:46)
>       #9      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
>       #10     CompilerContext.runInContext. (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:19)
>       #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
>       #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
>       #13     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
>       #14     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
>       #15     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:121:12)
>       #16     CompilerContext.runWithOptions (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:132:10)
>       #17     kernelForProgramInternal (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:59:32)
>       
>       #18     kernelForProgram (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:51:17)
>       
>       #19     compileToKernel (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:295:41)
>       
>       #20     FrontendCompiler.compile. (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:383:56)
>       #21     new Future. (dart:async/future.dart:176:37)
>       #22     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
>       #23     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
>       #24     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
>       #25     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
>       #26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
>       #27     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
>       #28     _CustomZone.bindCallback. (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
>       #29     Timer._createTimer. (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:21:15)
>       #30     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
>       #31     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
>       #32     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
>
> ```
> #0      BinaryBuilder.readComponent (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:450:7)
> #1      ProcessedOptions.loadComponent (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:393:10)
> #2      ProcessedOptions.loadSdkSummary (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:331:32)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> #3      generateKernelInternal.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:82:42)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> #4      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:24)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> #5      generateKernelInternal (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:69:10)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> #6      kernelForProgramInternal.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:60:35)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> #7      CompilerContext.runWithOptions.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:134:20)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> #8      CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
> ```
>
> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:46)
>       #9      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
>       #10     CompilerContext.runInContext. (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:19)
>       #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
>       #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
>       #13     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
>       #14     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
>       #15     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:121:12)
>       #16     CompilerContext.runWithOptions (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:132:10)
>       #17     kernelForProgramInternal (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:59:32)
>       
>       #18     kernelForProgram (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:51:17)
>       
>       #19     compileToKernel (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:295:41)
>       
>       #20     FrontendCompiler.compile. (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:383:56)
>       #21     new Future. (dart:async/future.dart:176:37)
>       #22     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
>       #23     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
>       #24     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
>       #25     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
>       #26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
>       #27     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
>       #28     _CustomZone.bindCallback. (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
>       #29     Timer._createTimer. (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:21:15)
>       #30     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
>       #31     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
>       #32     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
>
> ```
> Compiler failed on /Users/Yoji_work/StudioProjects/health_service/flutter_app/lib/main.dart
> Failed to package /Users/Yoji_work/StudioProjects/health_service/flutter_app.
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
> note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't fudamental solution, but I changed Flutter SDK version from v1.9.1+hotfix.2 (the latest stable version) to  1.7.8+hotfix.4 and it worked for now.

I'm gonna check release note and see differences between them.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You Just Update Your Flutter

`Flutter Upgrade` run on terminal